# how does the scroll view work like in doodle jump or papi jump?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

Im making an endless type game where the view scrolls similar to like doodle jump except it scrolls down vertically not up vertically. How do you accomplish this? Should I set Up a scroll view and and use the methods to manual scroll? I just feel like that would cause a memory leak after some time

Comment: I don't know if Doodle jump is really made with a scroll view. I would take a look into a game framework like cocos2d to develop a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a ScrollVIew, this is just OpenGL, or framework based on it (like aforementioned Cocos2D)

Comment: Just read some manuals. However, using Cocos2D or other libs would be much easier.